# Are these usages better off without the prepositions?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is it better to not add the preposition when using any of the usages below in daily conversation and in writing? Why? Will the answers vary from person to person?

> spend time (**on**) doing something / have no problem (**in**) doing something
>   / have difficulty (**in**) doing something / is no point (**in**) doing
>   something / is no use (**in**) doing something / Good luck (**in**) doing something / be busy (**in**) doing something

Comment: We usually say "I have no problem _with_..." and "Good luck _with_...". "It is no use doing..." is usually used without a preposition. In the other examples, it's optional. I don't know why, that's just the way English is used.

Comment: Also, we spend time doing an activity, but spend time on a task or project.

Comment: @KateBunting So, you don't often hear people saying "I have no problem doing something" and "Good luck doing something"?

Comment: Yes, people do say those things, but if a preposition is used it would normally be _with_ and not _in_.

Comment: @KateBunting I see. So when using _"have difficulty (in) doing something"_ or _"is no point (in) doing something"_  or _"be busy (in) doing something"_, whether to add the preposition is optional?

Comment: Yes, as I said in my original comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kate.